# Disable flask-admin validation for list of reference field

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I've made an API in `flask` and `MongoDB` (`MongoEngine`) and it's admin panel through `flask-admin`. I'm looking for a way to disable `flask-admin` validation for a field which is essentially **list of references field**.

For example:

```
class A(db.Document):
    pid = db.IntField(unique=True)
    Bs = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField(B, dbref=False, reverse_delete_rule=NULLIFY))
```

Here class A has a list field for references of class B. Model View for class A

```
class A(ModelView):
    can_create = True
    can_delete = True
    can_edit = True

def is_accessible(self):
    return current_user.has_role("admin")
```

Now if I try to create a new document of `class A` from `flask-admin`, it doesn't allow saying `Invalid Choice`. I can create a class A object only when I choose at least one B object to be referred in `A.Bs`. But I want to disable this validation. I want to create class A object even when initially there are no B's object are referenced.

The Code is correct and working through API. It's just flask-admin validation which is causing problem on initially creating objects of class A without linking to objects of class B.

This is possible through API but I'm finding no method to do it via admin panel. How can I disable this default validation only for this field initially or there is another method which is better?